# Is there a down side to using GlobalKey<NavigatorState> to do all my route navigation?

Tags: flutter

I have seen an example in flutter where you can navigate routes without having access to a BuildContext.

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed('/');
```

Are there any drawbacks to doing all of my apps navigation with this method?

Comment: Global keys are relatively expensive. If access to `context` is the sole reason you are doing this, there is likely an issue in the way you were trying to push routes.

Comment: "Relatively". The flutter docs say it is relatively expensive when using GlobalKey on frame redraws. But navigating screens are not in the hotpath, and relatively inexpensive.

Comment: The "expensive" part of GlobalKeys is unrelated to simply reading the state of a widget. I've opened a PR which updates the documentation.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Can you link the PR?

Comment: For `Navigator`, this is probably fine. It's debatable when you have 2 instances of `Navigator` (cupertino), but otherwise alright. Overall the real issue with GlobalKeys is that they break the contract of widgets (uni-directional data-flow).

Comment: The PR for the documentation update: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/62083 @ChristopherMoore

Comment: Ya but is the performance actually relevant in comparison to changing a screen?Remember the question is about GlobalKeys in general, its about using GlobalKey<NavigatorState> to change the screen.

Comment: Anyone can give me a solution for this relatable question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187470/navigator-with-global-key-does-not-work-as-expected-for-multiple-navigators-in-f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no downside.

The performance concern is negligible in regards to screen switches.